# Forms of "what language should I learn next"?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

It's not explicit in the question but, https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/128344/would-smalltalk-be-a-good-introduction-to-programming, to me is just another form of "Which language should I learn next?"  The OP has found an online resource and is, I think, really asking "is this a good introduction to programming for me".

I flagged it as "off topic", which was the closest match to what I was trying to express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's clearly off-topic per "What language should I learn next?" Closed.

Answer (score 2):

Saw your flag. I think it's closer to not constructive though, and as a rule of thumb I wait for a few other people to vote before I do. I'm leaving the flag open so the question can be referenced though.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @JoshK Are you back? We haven't seen you around in a while. :)